# Inserting/Update many rows with same timestamp

Tags: sqlite

If I have a file with a single transaction and many thousands of `INSERT` statements, can I count on `'now'` being the same for all of the `INSERT`s or must I find another way?   That is, in a simplified example, given:

```
create table things (
    fid     integer         not null primary key,
    name    character(32)   not null default '' unique,
    descr   character(128)  not null,
    lastupd date            not null default (strftime('%s','now'))
);

begin transaction;
insert into things (name, descr) values ('one', 'foo');
insert into things (name, descr) values ('two', 'bar');
   :
   :
insert into things (name, descr) values ('last', 'baz');
end transaction;
```

Will all the inserted rows contain the same value in lastupd?  I'm guessing not.  So maybe insert the current time into a temp table and refer to it in all the INSERTs with a WHERE clause?

So, in the unlikely event the above "works", adding an `ON CONFLICT` clause raises another question.  The following works, but (obviously) does not update the lastupd column:

```
insert into things (name, descr) values ('last', 'baz')
  on conflict (name) do update set
    descr = excluded.descr;
```

Trying:

```
insert ...
  on conflict (name) do update set
    descr   = excluded.descr,
    lastupd = excluded.lastupd;
```

complains **no such column excluded.lastupd**.

The following clause works:

```
  insert ...
  on conflict (name) do update set
    descr   = excluded.descr,
    lastupd = strftime('%s','now');
```

But it is definitely starting to feel like "there must be a better way".
Some kind of trigger perhaps?

Comment: It might change over multiple inserts, but shouldn't for one insert that adds multiple rows: *The 'now' argument to date and time functions always returns exactly the same value for multiple invocations within the same sqlite3_step() call.* Maybe an `UPDATE` afterwards?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the command buffer is large enough to do all of the rows in a single INSERT with multiple VALUE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be to use :-

```
begin transaction;
insert into things (name, descr,lastupd) values ('one', 'foo','[Error]');
insert into things (name, descr,lastupd) values ('two', 'bar','[Error]');
   :
   :
insert into things (name, descr,lastupd) values ('last', 'baz','[Error]');

update things set lastupd = (strftime('%s','now')) WHERE lastupd = '[Error]'; --<<<<<<<<<<
end transaction;
```

i.e. insert using an indicator value for the lastupd column (perhaps set the default as an indicator (as in the other question) in which case just insert using the original two columns) and after all inserts update all inserted rows (as per the indicator) using the single value for the timestamp for all inserts.

e.g. :-

```
create table things (
    fid     integer         not null primary key,
    name    character(32)   not null default '' unique,
    descr   character(128)  not null,
    lastupd date            not null default (strftime('[Error]'))
);

begin transaction;
insert into things (name, descr) values ('one', 'foo');
insert into things (name, descr) values ('two', 'bar');
insert into things (name, descr) values ('last', 'baz');
update things SET lastupd = (strftime('%s','now')) WHERE lastupd = '[Error]';
end transaction;
```

Results in :-

[image]